# How install SQL Server on PHP MacOS?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, macos

I downloaded and configured 2 files:

```
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

And install ODBC drive for macOS:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install --no-sandbox msodbcsql17 mssql-tool
```

But, when i run laravel with SQL Server, it appears the following error:

> Could not connect to the database. Please check your configuration.
>   error:PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the
>   Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server.
>   Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server
>   for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

I am use MacOS, MAMPP and code with Laravel.

Thank all!